# Postgresql tables dont show on navicat database ui manager

Tags: postgresql, navicat

I did allow all the privileges for the user on the database, it shows all the tables in pgadmin4 but not in navicat version 12. Anyone knows why it happens? Or did I miss something?

Comment: same here, I can't able to see the tables in a schema, navicat version 12.1.23 and postgresql version 12

Comment: me too, can't see tables in menu

Comment: Same here, I could not see either.

Comment: same here can't see the tables either